# navigating from a UserID to UserRoleId in a custom controller

Tags: soql, custom-controller

I've been stumped for awhile on this issue, although I believe there should be something very simple I can do!

I am building a custom controller for a Visualforce page and one function I am building is passed a userID where I then need to find that specific user's UserRoleId, then collect a set of roles under their role, and then select a list of subordinate users, seen below:

```
public static List<user> fetchUsersTeamMembers(Id userId){

    List<user> userA = [select Id, UserRoleId From User where Id=:userId LIMIT 1];
    Set<Id> allSubRoleIds = new Set<Id>();
    If(userA[0] != null){
        allSubRoleIds = getAllSubRoleIds(new Set<ID>{userA[0].UserRoleId});
    }

    List<user> userList = [select u.LastName,Name,u.Id, u.FirstName,u.Email
                          From User u where profile.Name='AMS Sales User' 
                          and isActive=true and (Id=:userId or UserRoleId 
                          in:allSubRoleIds) order by u.FirstName];

    return userList.size()>0 ? userList : new List<user>();
}


public static  Set<ID> getAllSubRoleIds(Set<ID> roleIds) {
    Set<ID> currentRoleIds = new Set<ID>();
    for(UserRole userRole :[select Id from UserRole where ParentRoleId  
         IN :roleIds AND ParentRoleID != null]) {
        currentRoleIds.add(userRole.Id);
    }    
    if(currentRoleIds.size() > 0) {
        currentRoleIds.addAll(getAllSubRoleIds(currentRoleIds));
    }
    return currentRoleIds;
}
```

There are no errors on save, but I am getting a List Index out of bounds error when trying to view my page.

First, Is there a more elegant solution to get the UserRoleId from the UserId, perhaps with a direct query on UserRoleId or even without SOQL?

If not, Do you see where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If(userA[0] != null){
```

This works in JavaScript, but in Apex Code, if the list is empty, you'll get an exception. Instead, check if the list is empty:

```
if(!userA.isEmpty()) {
```